# Material-table #1204 - How to customize the fonts in Groupbar, pagination in react js - Material table

Tags: reactjs, material-table

Font is looking small in every component, please suggest me to increase the font size explicitly in groupbar and pagination

How to install MuiThemeProvider, i am trying this also but saying component is not availble

Comment: Can you create a codepen to display your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install material-ui/core (it's a per-dependency of material-table). Import that and wrap your table or whole app with the Theme provider from material-ui/core and provide a theme.

Check out the docs. Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-with-grouped-rows-tjvxd).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I used MuiThemeProvider and resolved

Comment: <ThemeProvider theme={createMuiTheme({
    typography: {
      fontSize: 25,
    },
  })}> For anyone looking for a code example